# couchbase synchronous retrieval get API

Tags: couchbase, synchronous

I have ran into a problem while dealing with bucket.get() API of the couchbase. I need to see, if some set of DocIDs are already stored in couchbase server or not, if not then I need to do some XML parsing.

```
var policy_bucket = cluster.openBucket('ss_policy_db');
function someFun(){
    for (var i = 0; i < Policies.length; i++) {
        var Profile = Policies[i];
        var polID = Profile.get('id');
        var ret = retrievePolicyNew(polID)
        // do some action on the basis of ret.
    }
}   
function retrievePolicyNew(id) { 
    var result = policy_bucket.get(id.toString()); // TypeError: Second argument needs to be an object or callback.
    console.log(result);
    // return -1, on if we find the ID.
}
```

The problem with bucket.get() is that, it is a asynchronous (not properly know how to make synchronous call), I don't want to handle callback for every ID search. Is their any other way to search the list of ID in couchbase. It would be great if someone can help me getting synchronous call API set, that will solve my lot of other problems also. Because it not looks very good to make very small search also and handling it in callback.
I have stored very less data in DB, so performance is not a issue here.

Answer (score 0):

You should be able to use this in a synchronous manner.  I think either the code sample you provide above is incomplete and somewhere you're calling `CouchbaseBucket.async()` or something else.  In any case, [the docs are pretty clear that `get()`](http://docs.couchbase.com/sdk-api/couchbase-java-client-2.4.3/com/couchbase/client/java/Bucket.html#get-D-) takes a string and returns a `JsonDocument`